# JavaScript: Remove Double Quotes - JSON.Stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

After using he JSON.stringify() method in JavaScript to allow JSON data render in the browser it outputs double quotations " " at either end of the property rendered in the browser - any idea how to resolve this?

Here is my code -

```
<li class="divider">Brown Eyes</li>
<div id="output1"></div>
<li class="divider">Green Eyes</li>
<div id="output2"></div>

<script>
    var myContainer = "";

    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dwnm", true);
    a.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(a);
        if (a.readyState == 4) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(a.responseText);
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                if (obj[i].eyeColor == 'brown') {
                var myContainer = "<ul class='list'><li>" + obj[i].name.first + " " + obj[i].name.last + " - " + obj[i].eyeColor + "</li></ul>";
                var myContainer = JSON.stringify(myContainer);
                document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML += myContainer;    
                }
                if (obj[i].eyeColor == 'green') {
                var myContainer = "<ul class='list'><li>" + obj[i].name.first + " " + obj[i].name.last + " - " + obj[i].eyeColor + "</li></ul>";
                var myContainer = JSON.stringify(myContainer);
                document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML += myContainer;    
                }
            }
        }

    }
    a.send();
</script>
```

Comment: You're calling `JSON.stringify()` on something that is already a string. It's meant to be used on a JavaScript object, not html.

Comment: @Gavin - you're right. I commented the " var myContainer = JSON.stringify(myContainer);" piece out and the quotes were removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "`<ul class='list'><li>Faye Garrett - brown</li></ul>`" is not a valid JSON string.

Uncomment your stringify lines and it works.